# Reactjs state not updating

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
  constructor(props) {

    super(props);
    this.state = {
      active: false,
      showSideBar: false,
      className: ""
    }
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    if (this.props.overlay) {
      this.setState({
        className: "wrapper_overlay"
      });
      alert(this.state.className);
    }
    else if (this.props.SideBarWithIcon) {
      this.setState({
        className: "wrapper_clopsed"
      });
    }
  }
```

I am updating my state with the help of the props but the component is getting props but state is not updating

Comment: You can ditch the constructor and directly write state = {}. For more info: https://hackernoon.com/the-constructor-is-dead-long-live-the-constructor-c10871bea599

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`setState` is asynchronous. Just alert in a callback to the method instead.

```
if (this.props.overlay) {
  this.setState(
    { className: "wrapper_overlay" },
    () => alert(this.state.className);
  );
}
```

Note: you can, and should, also use `shouldComponentUpdate` to check for when a `setState` call completes

Answer (score 3):

Since [setstate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) is async in nature so you maynot see updated state in alert.
You can use that in callback which will be called once the setstate is done. like this

```
componentDidMount() {
    if (this.props.overlay) {
      this.setState({
        className: "wrapper_overlay"
      }, ()=> {alert(this.state.className);});
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

[State updates may be asynchronous](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous)

> React may batch multiple setState() calls into a single update for
>   performance.
>
> Because this.props and this.state may be updated asynchronously, you
>   should not rely on their values for calculating the next state.

```
// Wrong
this.setState({
    className: "wrapper_overlay"
  });
```

> To fix it, use a second form of setState() that accepts a function
>   rather than an object.

```
// Correct
this.setState((state, props) => ({
  className: "wrapper_overlay"
}));
```

or just

```
this.setState(() => ({
  className: "wrapper_overlay"
}));
```

Answer (score 1):

In React.js, running program thread does not wait for setting state and continues its execution, until and unless operation defined in `setState()` callback.

Your state is getting set but as your `alert()` is after setstate i.e. not in callback of `setState()` that's why its getting previous value because at the time state is setting new value, thread is not waiting but executing the next instruction which is `alert()`.

```
if (this.props.overlay) {
    this.setState({ className: "wrapper_overlay" }, () => alert(this.state.className););
}
```

Hope this works for you.

Answer (score 1):

> Just use the callback method to update the state, as 
>   setState() might work asynchronously.

```
        this.setState(() => {
            className: "wrapper_clopsed"
        });
```