# State is not updating. I want to fetch data from the firestore

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks

I have successfully retrieved data from the firestore but I am not able to update my state.
Please check the code.

```
export const TaskContextProvider = (props) => {

    const [Tasks, setTasks] = useState([])

    const { User } = useContext(AuthContext)

    useEffect(() => {
        firebase.firestore()
        .collection("Users")
        .doc(User.id)
        .collection("Tasks")
        .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
            const newtask = snapshot.docs.map((doc)=>({
                id : doc.id,
                ...doc.data()
            }))
            setTasks(newtask)
            console.log('newtask', newtask)
            console.log('Tasks', Tasks)
        })
    }, [])
```

the console output of the following is

```
newtask (10) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
Tasks []
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reactjs state not updating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54320478/reactjs-state-not-updating)

Answer (score 0):

`setTasks` is asyncronous and may never show you the correct value when called from within the same function that's setting its new value. Instead, log it outside of the `useEffect` to see if it is actually updating or not. Then you will see a console.log for each render.